# Integrate using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

This was a question on my complex analysis take home final. Since the semester is over and grades have been posted I believe I can post it now.

Let $a > 0$ and $b > 0$. Verify that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{e^{a x}+e^{-b x}} = \frac{\pi}{(a+b) \sin{\left (\frac{a \pi}{a+b} \right )}} $$

(Using Residue Theorem)

I believe we have to choose a rectangular contour which contains exactly one of the
singularities.

Comment: Alternately, let $t=e^x$ and substitute $u=\dfrac1{1+t^{a+b}}$ , then recognize the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, and use [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties), so as to finally arrive at the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the integrand as

$$\frac{e^{\left (\frac{b-a}{2} x \right )}}{2 \cosh{\left (\frac{a+b}{2} x \right )}} $$

Thus consider the contour integral

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{\left (\frac{b-a}{2} z \right )}}{2 \cosh{\left (\frac{a+b}{2} z \right )}} $$

where $C$ is the rectangle with vertices $\pm R \pm i 2 \pi/(a+b)$.  The contour integral is then

$$\int_{-R}^R dx \frac{e^{\left (\frac{b-a}{2} x \right )}}{2 \cosh{\left (\frac{a+b}{2} x \right )}} + i \int_0^{2 \pi/(a+b)}dy \frac{e^{\left (\frac{b-a}{2} (R+i y) \right )}}{2 \cosh{\left (\frac{a+b}{2} (R+i y) \right )}} \\ + \int_{R}^{-R} dx \frac{e^{\left (\frac{b-a}{2} (x+i 2 \pi/(a+b)) \right )}}{2 \cosh{\left (\frac{a+b}{2} (x+i 2 \pi/(a+b) \right )}} + i \int_{2 \pi/(a+b)}^0 dy \frac{e^{\left (\frac{b-a}{2} (-R+i y) \right )}}{2 \cosh{\left (\frac{a+b}{2} (-R+i y) \right )}}$$

It should be clear that the second and fourth integrals vanish as $R \to \infty$, as both $a$ and $b$ are positive.

The contour integral is also equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=i \pi/(a+b)$.  Thus, we have

$$\left [1+e^{i \pi (b-a)/(a+b)} \right ]\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{\left (\frac{b-a}{2} x \right )}}{2 \cosh{\left (\frac{a+b}{2} x \right )}} = i 2 \pi \frac{e^{i \pi/2 \left (\frac{b-a}{a+b} \right )}}{(a+b) i}$$

The result follows after a little algebra.

Comment: That was quick. It took me hrs to do it :) I did it without re-writing as Cosh.

Comment: @Shrey I think it is also possible using the following function. Was it also your choice? $$f(z) = \frac{e^{bz}}{e^{(a+b)z}+1}$$ (I like the question *and the answer* btw :) )

Comment: @dietervdf Yes. I did exactly that. I believe we can also solve the integral by dividing  by e(ax) but in that case we do not get the required result.